# Powershell test script returns error "The term '=' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program"

Tags: linux, powershell, scripting

powershell users!
If I run powershell as shell and type commands one by one  - weverything's good.
But if I put commands into .ps1 file and try to execte it I receive weird error:

```
The term '=' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program
```

test script I run:

```
echo "$pw = 2" > ./test.ps1
echo '$pw' >> ./test.ps1
pwsh ./test.ps1
```

I use pwsh on linux (installed from https://packages.microsoft.com/rhel/7/prod/) if it matters.

tried to use "$pw=2` - same result.

Yes, I know about long form of setting and getting variable:

```
echo "set-variable -name 'pw' -value '2'" > ./test.ps1
echo "get-variable -name 'pw'" >> ./test.ps1
pwsh ./test.ps1
```

It works. But I want more complicated  scripts where get-variable  can be hardly used.

Please help - what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you enter the script in  bash or pwsh? Remember variables inside double quotes are expanded. So `echo '$pw = 2' > ./test.ps1` should do. In pwsh the `echo` is superfluous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to escape the `$` dollar sign indicating a variable name.

```
# command                       # result
Set-StrictMode -Off             # uninitialized variables are assumed to have a value of 0 (zero) or $null
echo "$pw = 2"                  #  = 2
Set-StrictMode -Version Latest  # Selects the latest (most strict) version available
echo "$pw = 2"                  # throws an error: The variable '$pw' cannot be retrieved because it has not been set.
echo '$pw = 2'                  # $pw = 2       (used single quotes)
echo "`$pw = 2"                 # $pw = 2       (used backtick escape character)
```

**Edit** the above example was tested in Windows Powershell. However, it works with the same results in WSL `Ubuntu` shell omitting all the `Set-StrictMode` stuff **and** using the `\` backslash escape character as follows:

```
# command                       # result
echo "$pw = 2"                  #  = 2
echo '$pw = 2'                  # $pw = 2       (used single quotes)
echo "\$pw = 2"                 # $pw = 2       (used backslash escape character)
```

Reference:

- Bash: [Quotes and escaping](https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting)
- Powershell:

  - [About Quoting Rules](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-6)
  - [`Set-StrictMode` (Module: `Microsoft.PowerShell.Core`)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/Set-StrictMode?view=powershell-3.0)

Comment: :wall: I know about double quotes normally - but there I forgot about it totally. Thanks!